# gcc exception handler modify return address

Tags: c, gcc, arm, interrupt-handling

I'm currently writing some bare-metal code for, among others, armv6-m using (arm-none-eabi-)gcc as compiler.

When implementing the exception-handlers I stumbled upon `__attribute__((interrupt("type")))` ([manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html)) telling gcc to generate a function that preserves all registers (apart from banked ones).

The problem is that this generated function always (more or less) returns execution to wherever it was supposed to be before the interrupt. While desirable for regular interrupts, this is exactly not what you want when dealing with e.g. undefined instruction exceptions, as you then spin on said undefined instruction. While I can find a macro that is supposed to get me the return address, I can't find one to set or modify it. This seems like an obvious thing to be included with e.g. the type `"undef"` as returning to the old pc is basically guaranteed to just retrigger the exception.

TLDR: Is there some way to modify the return address of an interrupt handler or a general c function in gcc?

And please don't tell me to just write an assembly wrapper, I know that would fix it & already have a few of those, but if this work is already done by gcc I'd prefer to not worry about register clobbering and optimization myself.

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need to put the attribute for armv6-m, because the processor itself preserves all caller-saved registers before jumping to the interrupt vector. It's kind of a main selling point of the new exception model for cortex-m.

Comment: @EOF thanks for that info, so the additional stuff generated by GCC should be nothing. This would also imply it's actually getting the return-address from the stack it saved the context to (manual confirms this, LR points to reserved address). This would mean to change the return address I have to change whatever is on that stack, correct?

Comment: You can find the details in *ARM v6-M Architecture Reference Manual*, `B1.5
ARMv6-M exception model`, which includes the stack layout with the return address in `B1.5.6 Exception entry behavior`. I'm not certain, but I would expect some library support for this to exist (because it's necessary for task switching), maybe in CMSIS?

Comment: I personally don't think it is worth it.  See: [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48429).  While a extremely simple bare metal might make sense, there can be different thing that must be saved/restored in an OS to keep consistency.  The different exceptions have different banked registers and the register use is a main job of a compiler.  For some simple case, there might be a right answer, but putting the code around a wrapper that save/restores context will always end up actually being more versatile.